# What are the best practices to back up your production environment for a web app?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, php, backup, cloud

I am running 2 boxes on hetzner and would like to figure out the best way to back up the
- app
- data
- live environment

I understand that for the app and data parts, its very specific to my web service, so I am not going to go into too much detail here. But would really appreciate a general answer assuming the basics like LAMP on Ubuntu.

I am currently doing the following -

1. Hetzner provided backup
2. Daily SQL dump onto remote drive (and replicated onto at least 2 separate locations)

What else should I consider?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

it all depends on how precious your data is and how much can you spend on backups. few random thoughts:

- monitor your backups - make alerting system that notifies you if any of commands during your backup fails [ you can use [trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/185900/104398) ]
- verify your backups from time to time - eg restore on a test site every quarter
- if possible try to keep backups offline or at least use pull method not push [backup host logs into your production server to take backup, not the other way around] - in this way even if your server gets compromised and malicious attacker wipes it out she will be unable to delete your backups.
- keep your backups secure... ideally - i'd have host not accessible from the internet [eg computer behind firewall or nat or both] initiate all backup procedure pulling all your data, file system level encryption like truecrypt for the backups host does not hurt either
- keep few past backups - you can compress full dumps into separate archives and rotate them eg monthly or take advantage of tool like [rdiff-backup](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/). in case you screw something up and notice it only after few days it can be a life saver.
- how busy your site is? if there are plenty of updates/inserts to the sql - consider having mysql replication slave with binary logging of all master queries turned on it. in this way you will be able to restore [at least the sql content] up to the moment before crash.
- check if backups affect badly performance of your site, if needed use some throttling [ionice, rate limit for rsync or [xtrabackup](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/05/20/hint-throttling-xtrabackup/)].

Comment: perfect answer +1

Comment: Kudos for mentioning Percona Xtrabackup, which is a much better tool than mysqldump.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can add to pQd's answer: Keep off-site backups. If Hetzner ever goes down or bankrupt, you'll be happy you have them.